# PyInstaller; "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyinstaller, static-linking

My PyInstaller spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\admin\\compile'],
             binaries=[('C:\\Python361\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\plugins\\platforms\\qwindows.dll', 'qwindows.dll')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False , icon='icon.ico')
```

So I have ran into the problem where I will compile my PyQt5 5.8.2 (with Python 3.6.1) program with the latest version of PyInstaller from pip, and it works! The statically linked, onefile executable works on my computer with all the Qt stuff on it.

But then I test it on any computer or virtual machine that doesn't have the Qt environment set up already, and it crashes on start because of the "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin 'windows'" error. If you look at the spec you'll notice that I attempted to store the DLL in the binary list manually so PyInstaller would store it in the executable, but that didn't work.

I would like to know what I need to change so that I can compile my application without having to do something like include the platforms folder in the folder with the executable (I want everything to be in the executable), would it be as simple as a change in the spec file that I didn't realize so that it stores the DLL in the executable?

By the way, this is not a duplicate. I looked at some of the other questions and all of them were either for a different type of application or the solution was to downgrade or store the DLL in the folder and I can't do either of those.

EDIT: So I changed it to onedir just to see if it was even in there, and qwindows.dll is inside of the folder. There is also a qt5_plugins folder which has a platforms folder which also has a qwindows.dll. So how is it not detecting the dll??

Comment: You can try adding the path to those libraries in the pathex variable

Comment: Just tried that by changing to pathex=['C:\\Users\\admin\\compile', 'C:\\Python361\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\plugins\\platforms'], didn't change anything

Comment: Also @The4thIceman I am doing this from a clean virtual machine if that matters

Comment: I edited the question since I found an important detail.

Answer (score 8):

There seem to be two solutions, the first one worked fine for me:

- copy platform directory to directory of your executable. You'll find the platform directory at a location like `c:\Users\<username>\envs\<environmentname>\Library\plugins\platforms` **or**
- Upgrade to a newer version of pyqt: `conda install -c anaconda pyqt`

Use the second option with care: Do not try to use pip for pyqt installation if you have a conda environment, this might break your conda installation: 
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1970

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue where my python code worked fine, but the compiled .exe file would provide the "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows" problem. I fixed the problem by copying the `~PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms` folder from the program's directory, generated by using `pyinstaller --onedir main.py`, to the folder holding the .exe file.

It seems that in my case the only way "helping" my program detect the required .dlls was having the `platforms` folder next to the `main.exe`. Pasting the `platforms` folder to the program's directory after using `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` also makes the program work.

Comment: It worked for me.

I have an "app" compiled with *pyinstaller* that involves *matplotlib* and *seaborn* graphics. The executable works but gives the error when the plots pop up. Running the python scrips within Pycharm works correctly.

I copied the folder `platforms` located, in my case, in `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins` --> problem solved

Answer (score 1):

I just update my pyqt5 package to 5.10.1 and fix that.

Comment: comment quality

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with PyQt6 6.0.3 and PyInstaller 4.3.

First a tried a one-folder bundle which worked fine after adding the platform and style plugins to the `binaries` list and `PyQt6.sip` to the `hiddenimports` one (The latter may be need only if using PyQt6).

When i tried the one-file bundle i got the platform plugin error. First i checked if the files are being copied by looking in the temp folder where the bundle is unpacked during runtime (with the error dialog open) and all the DLL's were there. When i copied then to the same folder as the executable it worked fine, the problem was Qt wasn't finding them in the temp folder.

I found the solution reading about `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/deployment-plugins.html) then looking in this PyInstaller [commit](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/5534/commits/4a29e8fc4b32869b45f44f8918c5e9363e6f3bcc#diff-dd5b4720054ebab8f44d75e3db0598642dca589a2ecddc8378d339b21599f0fcR19).

**After adding the plugins' DLLs just add a runtime hook to set `QT_PLUGIN_PATH`.**

Also if using UPX the plugins' DLLs need to be added to the `upx_exclude` list.

Here's the hook and spec file i used, with default options removed:

### pyQtHook.py

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

os.environ['QT_PLUGIN_PATH'] = str( Path( sys._MEIPASS ) / 'PyQt6/Qt6' )
```

### oneFile.spec

```
from pathlib import Path

root = Path.cwd()
qtRoot = root / 'env/Lib/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt6'

analysis = Analysis(
    scripts = [
        root / 'src/main.py',
    ],
    pathex = [
        root,
        qtRoot / 'bin',
    ],
    binaries = [
        ( qtRoot / 'plugins/platforms/qwindows.dll', 'PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/platforms' ),
        ( qtRoot / 'plugins/styles/qwindowsvistastyle.dll', 'PyQt6/Qt6/plugins/styles' ),
    ],
    hiddenimports =[
        'PyQt6.sip',
    ],
    runtime_hooks = [
        'pyQtHook.py',
    ],
)

pyz = PYZ( analysis.pure, analysis.zipped_data )

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    analysis.scripts,
    analysis.binaries,
    analysis.zipfiles,
    analysis.datas,
    name = 'MyApp',
    console = False,
    upx = True,
    upx_exclude = [
        'qwindows.dll',
        'qwindowsvistastyle.dll',
    ],
)
```

Comment: I'am trying the same as you did like for hours. No way... Still the same error... :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I have been looking for a solution to this issue for days now and I finally managed to fix it WITHOUT having to manually copy the folder.
Since this question also uses the `.spec` file I thought this would be the right place.
The idea is that the `.exe` is looking for the `.dll`s in the path `./platforms/*.dll` so I simply added all of the dlls to the binaries array in the spec file, where their path within the bundle is `platforms/*.dll`. This is because `binaries` is an array of tuples where the first value is the path to the file and the second one is the path within the bundle (so pretty much the path inside the .exe "container").

Besides that, the top states `mode: python` which I assume means it is executed as a python script, therefore it should support variables, strings and concatenation. So my spec file ended up looking something like this:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

pf_foldr='C:\\Users\\Gabryxx7\\anaconda3\\envs\\<env_name>\\Library\\plugins\\platforms\\'

a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Gabryxx7\\PycharmProjects\\<proj_name>\\program.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Gabryxx7\\PycharmProjects\\<proj_name>\\'],
             binaries=[(pf_foldr+'qwindows.dll', 'platforms\\qwindows.dll'),
             (pf_foldr+'qdirect2d.dll', 'platforms\\qdirect.dll'),
             (pf_foldr+'qoffscreen.dll', 'platforms\\qoffscreen.dll'),
             (pf_foldr+'qwebgl.dll', 'platforms\\qwebgl.dll')
             ],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['GUI', 'API', 'Threading', 'ssl', 'pyodbc'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='programName',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True ) # False to avoid the console
```

I had previously tried every solution I found online: setting up the environmental variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH`, reinstalling Anaconda, updating all the packages, tried with PyPi version and no venvs, but nothing worked. In the end copying the `platforms` folder with the `dlls` did the trick and so did the spec file editing to avoid the manual step.

Comment: this appears to not be working when using winx64, python 3.7.x, venv + pyside6.

Answer (score 0):

After almost explode my  brain trying to solve this problem I figure out a solution that worked for me.

inside the SPEC file I added the clause: `upx_exclude=['qwindows.dll'],`

Turns out this DLL is corrupted when compressed during the freezing process by PyInstaller. Adding the DLL to the `upx_exclude` clause prevent this problem of occuring.

You can check part of my SPEC file here:

```
...

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='Hydro Tax Automation App',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=['qwindows.dll'],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False)
```