# pyinstaller - when freeze the app QtWebEngineWidgets throws dll error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qtwebengine

I have a code that have `QtWebEngineWidgets` module from `PyQt5`. it works fine in raw form (.py) but throws the following .dll and openGL missing error when freeze through pyinstaller. `PyQt5` and `pyinstaller` are both upto date.

Also, for your information, i am running this code on amazon c2 instance.

[image: IMAGE OF THE ERROR]

Comment: You should probably consult the PyInstaller documentation on how to handle errors at runtime - most likely you will have to explicitly add these DLLs during the PyInstaller build.

Comment: @barny i added these DLLs as well but its not working either

Comment: With the same error message?

Comment: @barny yes with the same message but one more arrising as well, which is something MSVCR100.dll missing

Comment: Did you check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468705/pyinstaller-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows

Comment: Does it work when running on your host/test env?

Comment: @barny yes it is working find in .py file and in python env but when i build/freeze through pyinstaller, it throws that error.

Comment: Does the frozen version run on your host/test env?

Comment: no i am freezing the .py on the same host/env. The raw/.py file works fine but when freezes through pyinstaller throws the upper errors

Comment: i also tried methods mentioned in the upper question you posted and the error is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the issue of Anaconda, the following command when run on the cmd, the error will be fix

```
set QT_OPENGL=desktop
```

[solution in Anaconda Issues](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9142)